# Django Queryset - get last related object and filter by it's data

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two Django Models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField()

class PersonData(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    phone = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

New `PersonData` objects are added when their information changes, but old ones are kept. And then I want to have a filter, which will filter persons by their data from the latest `PersonData` object they are related to.

I have the following queryset:

```py
filter_email = "email@example.com"
filter_phone = "964477425"

qs = Person.objects.all()

if filter_email:
    qs = qs.filter(persondata__email__icontains=filter_email)
if filter_phone:
    qs = qs.filter(persondata__phone__icontains=filter_phone)
```

But that filter searches through every `PersonData` object associated with `Person`. Is it possible to restrict this filter to only the latest `PersonData` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a popular type of query where latest/oldest entry against unique values of one field are desired.

I would like to say that if you think over what other answers suggest deeply, you'll understand they do not serve the purpose.

There is no way to fetch the `whole object` with desired filter in single **django** query (`Note that it is possible to get one field but not all fields, also it is possible to fetch all fields in raw **sql** queries`).

One of the ways I know to tackle this problem is to have a foreign-key in `Person` to the latest `PersonData` object, and update it each time new object of `PersonData` is created.

Comment: You're right. Having a foreign key to the latest PersonData object will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Yes it will, and your query will be exactly what it is now assuming you name foreign-key field as `persondata` although i'd suggest naming it `latest_data` :) .

Answer (score -2):

So you could try query to `PersonData` model:

```
qs = PersonData.objects.filter()

if filter_email:
    qs = PersonData.objects.filter(email__icontains=filter_email)
if filter_phone:
    qs = PersonData.objects.filter(phone__icontains=filter_phone)

# Cache Person object and pick the last
qs = qs.select_related('person').last()
```

Comment: this will not result in latest `PersonData` objects of each `Person`, rather just last `PersonData` object of all those passing the filter.